# Debugging an Android application directly on a device

Tags: android-emulator, android

I'm developing for Android under Ubuntu 10.04 with Eclipse and also with Intellij Idea. If I deploy and debug on virtual devices everything is OK.

I would like to run my applications directly on my Samsung Galaxy Tab. Therefore I plugged it to the USB port, switched on the "USB Debugging" in the Settings and I added a udev rule for the galaxy tab.

If i call ~/android-sdk-linux_86/platform-tools/adb devices I get also the output, that my samsung galaxy tab is connected. The output is:

List of devices attached
1000abdb6248    device

Its also possible to connect to the logcat. If i call ./adb logcat I get the log from my galaxy tab.

I am sure, this is my galaxy tab. Because when I plug off the tab, this device disappears.

But unfortunately I do not see the device in Eclipse or Idea in the AVD Manager.

The "Choose Device" dialog is empty. But I am able to start virtual devices without problems.

Any idea how to run and debug application directly on the galaxy tab from the IDE?

Thanks
   frafu

Comment: I never have issue with debugging with real device, in Eclipse. Only some times you need to reset the ADB to get the logCat refreshed; but I don't have a Galaxy Tab, maybe you check the AVD Manager, in 3rd party section, see if there's tools/driver from Samsung?

Comment: Same for me, nexus one and ubuntu works fine without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!
In eclipse it was my fault. I don't know why, but after some stops and starts from eclipse and the adb server it worked.

In IntelliJ Idea I found the error, because I launched the IDE accidentally from the command line and saw an error in the console:
31:42 E/adb: Failed to get the adb version: Cannot run program "/home/frafu/devtools/android-sdk-linux_86/tools/adb": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

That seems to be a Idea failure or i missconfigured something. The adb executable is not located in /tools but in /platform-tools. So I made an symlink in tools/adb -> ../platform-tools/adb and now also IntelliJ Idea runs!

Thank you for your attention. :-)

frafu

Answer (score 1):

The adb tool has moved to platform-tools/

If you don't see this directory in your SDK,
launch the SDK and AVD Manager (execute the android tool)
and install "Android SDK Platform-tools"

Please also update your PATH environment variable to
include the platform-tools/ directory, so you can
execute adb from any location.

so:

```
 ln -s ./platform-tools/adb ./tools/adb
```

also make sure eclipse has necessary permission.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that newer SDKs contains a txt file (adb_has_moved.txt) under the folder tools that says:

The adb tool has moved to platform-tools/

If you don't see this directory in your SDK,
launch the SDK and AVD Manager (execute the android tool)
and install "Android SDK Platform-tools"

Please also update your PATH environment variable to
include the platform-tools/ directory, so you can
execute adb from any location.

**Solution 1:**

Create a soft link to the abd binary and adding it to your path.

```
ln -s ./platform-tools/abd ./tools/abd
```

edit your .bashrc and add:

```
PATH= :/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:$PATH
export PATH
```

**Solution 2:**

Avoid creating the link and modify your path as suggested above:

```
PATH= /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools:/opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH
```

This works for eclipse and also IntelliJ IDEA.
I hope this helps someone